# Cucumber Eclipse - Resolving warning: Cucumber-JVM's --format option is deprecated. Please use --plugin instead

Tags: eclipse, installation, cucumber, appium, cucumber-jvm

Running Cucumber with Eclipse and getting the following warning:

**Cucumber-JVM's --format option is deprecated. Please use --plugin instead**

Tried to use Eclipse search functionality to search for "--format" and "format" but unable to find the relevant file I need to change.  Any ideas?

Comment: just re-word `--format` to `--plugin`

Answer (score 1):

In

`cucumber-java/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/cucumber/java/run/CucumberJavaRunConfigurationProducer.java`

change

`public static final String FORMATTER_OPTIONS = " --format org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter --monochrome";`

to

`public static final String FORMATTER_OPTIONS = " --plugin pretty";`

Comment: Why would you change the class definition file?

Comment: This is the fix for the --format errors on Github. This will be released in the upcoming version.

Comment: Did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 0):

`--format` is deprecated and will be removed in Cucumber v3.x

In your Run Configurations change `--format org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter` (or whatever the Eclipse equivalent is) to `--plugin pretty`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue in Intellij IDE. Below steps solved it!

1. Go to Run
2. Click Edit configurations..
3. Rename --Format to --plugin
4. Click Ok and Run feature file again

[image: Screenshot]