# Not able to run cucumber. Getting error "WARNING: Cucumber-JVM's --format option is deprecated. Please use --plugin instead"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am new to cucumber, i am learning from the scratch, when i try to execute my 1st feature file i am getting this error. I searched in google about this error, as per my findings i replaced --format with --plugin.But still when i try to execute i am getting the same error. To be specific i cleaned the workspace and i switched new workspace but nothing helps me...Please help me on this.
My Codings are below:

```
package cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty","json:target/cucumber.json"},
        features = {"src/cucumber/"}
        )

public class CucumberRunner {

    }
```

myfeature.feature

```
Feature: Checking login authentication

Scenario: Check loign

Given I am in application page
When I given login credentials
Then I check i am on home page
And I close the browser
```

Comment: Warnings are not an error. Anyway, your question seems to be already answered here, though the answer hasn't been accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29342004/5280532

Comment: In ur link where should i find this path..  cucumber-java/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/cucumber/java/run/CucumberJavaRunConfigurationProducer.java

Comment: Hi, please help me someone. I am not able to proceed with the solution given by Sva.Mu it is not clear.